# Symfony entity manager injection in the Entities

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I ask this question to understand.

In the Symfony envirment 2.5 there are alot posts about this topic on stack overflow. Some people need to access to entity manager from the entity to create a method "save()" for exaple.

It is clear form the answers that IS A VERY BAD PRACTISE do that , but my needs are quite different.

I dont have the problem of the persistence of the objects, that is made always from the controllers.

I have a sensor entity that do some very complex query to retrive some basic data like a series of data, or integer numbers.

I've for exaple an entity sensor. And I find particulary useful be able to do something like this:

```
$temperature = $sensor->getTemperature();
```

or do in a twig

```
{sensor.getTemperature()}
```

where `getTemperature()` is a very complex method with a very complex MySQL DQL query.

When I impement new data gatering methods on the entities, they become immediatly available to the view, withoud touch the controller the front end programmer just insert `$sensor->getNewMethod();` and is done.

I'm trying to make my code more polish and understanding better Symfony. Is there any good way to do it following a correct structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I need such method in my templates -  I usually create a twig function for such purposes:

example:

```
...

public function getFunctions()
{
    return [
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('get_category_hierarchy', [$this, 'getCategoryHierarchy']),
        ...
    ];
}

....

public function getCategoryHierarchy(CategoryTerm $categoryTerm = null)
{
    // some heavy logic here

    return $categoryHierarchy;
}
```

usage (in templates):

```
get_category_hierarchy(category_term)
```

If I need it outside of templates better create a service:

```
public function getSomeHeavyData(Entity $entity)
{
    // some heavy logic here

    return $data;
}
```

usage (for.ex in controller):

```
$myService = $this->get('my_service');
$data = $myService->getSomeHeavyData($entity);
```

Comment: this seems a good way make the code more polish and make more simple the integration of new functions between the backend and frontend letting the controller the same. I will give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your research is correct - you don't want to do this in the entity.  What you can do though is specify a Doctrine repository for your entity and then use that for your calculations.  So whenever you needed to calculate you would do:

```
$em->getRepository('MyBundle:Sensor')
    ->getTemperature($sensor);
```

You could also define a service and use that call your query instead.

Comment: Following this way , i'm not able to manage the new methods direclty form the view but i've to pass the variable alredy populated from the controller right?

Comment: Yes you'd have to fetch your entity first and pass to the repository method

Answer (score 0):

You can make your entity an service and inject it with entity manager. 
But still better to leave entity for mapping(setters, getters) and use repository.